# Llamar datasource por afuera del servidor de aplicaciones

Tags: java, tomcat

estoy con el desarrollo de una aplicación la cual tiene una web y esta a su vez llama con php a servicios de java. 
Los servicios de java están deployados en un ApplicationServer
Este war. a su vez depende de un conector del tipo *.jar y no se encuentra dentro del applicationServer por lo cual, al querer invocar un datasources alojado en el ApplicationServer no lo encuentra.

Mi duda es, para llamar a un datasource que se encuentra dentro del applicationserver tengo que estar dentro del mismo, o sea -: si o sí debe ser una aplicación web, o puedo tener un jar alojado en el mismo servidor pero no el TOMCAT y llamar al mismo ??

Desde ya agradezco su respuesta.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la aplicación web (java) depende de un jar, por ejemplo, de la clase de un conector de base de datos, podes poner el jar con el conector en tomcat en el directorio lib, o podés poner el conector como una dependencia del proyecto y que se incluya en el war.

Si trabajas con maven, en el primer caso seria una dependencia "provided" y en el segundo no.

Supongo que si ninguno de estos casos resuelve el problema puede haber soluciones más complejas como utilizar un classloader que busque el jar en forma remota de otro servidor:

```
URL url = new URL("file:///E:/Computing/Master/classes/" );
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});
Class clazz = ucl.loadClass("com.counter.controller.Action");
ProcessAlgorithm iAction = (ProcessAlgorithm) clazz.newInstance();
```

En el ejemplo usa un archivo, pero podría haber sido "https://...".

Como nota al margen, antes de cargar un jar remoto tenés que estar seguro de que el archvio viene de una fuente segura y sobre una conexión segura.
En lo particular evitaría esta opción.

[Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963273/how-to-use-classloader-to-load-class-file-from-server-to-client)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona.